# print out php values of array in individual divs

Tags: php, html, arrays, printing, html-lists

I get the page ids of a certain wordpress post_type and store them in an array, like so:

```
<?php $post_ids = get_posts(array(
    'fields'          => 'ids', // Only get post IDs
    'post_type' => 'projekt',
    'posts_per_page'  => -1
));
print_r($post_ids);
?>
```

The array looks like this: Array ( [0] => 9460 [1] => 8092 [2] => 7910 [3] => 7338 [4] => 6643 [5] => 4946 )

Now I am using these array values to get the id_value "projekt_name" of each of these pages and ideally want to echo each of them in its own div, like so:

```
    echo '<ul class="display-posts-desktop-slider">';

foreach($post_ids as $id => $id_value) {
$other_page = $id_value;
$ergebnis = the_field('projekt_name', $other_page) ;

    echo '<div class="test"><li><?php' . $ergebnis . '?></li></div>';

}

    echo '</ul>';
```

The problem I am facing is that a list item is correctly created for each of these but the values in the variable $ergebnis are printed outside of the list, as plain text without any class etc.

Question: How do I get to echo each value as its own list item, eg. place them inside the li tag...? I hope I could describe whats happening and thank you loads for your time and help.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have just a little mistake in there, concretely

`echo '<div class="test"><li><?php' . $ergebnis . '?></li></div>';`

You should change this line to

`echo "<div class='test'><li>$ergebnis</li></div>';"`

I've tried it with this line using my own temporary array and it worked.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Hi and thank you much for your help!
unfortunately this does not help it. I think the " and ; need to be swaped and theres one too many ' in there but even with this, the structure is as follows: 
<div><li></li></div>
$ergebnis1
<div><li></li></div>
$ergebnis2

what I want to achieve is 
<div><li>$ergebnis1</li></div>
<div><li>$ergebnis2</li></div>

Answer (score 0):

I solved it and the mistake I made was that

```
the_field('projekt_name', $other_page) ;
```

automatically prints the result. So

```
foreach($post_ids as $id => $id_value) {
$other_page = $id_value;


    echo '<div class="testtesttest">'; 

$ergebnis = the_field('projekt_name', $other_page) ;

echo '</div>';
```

now prints every $ergebnis into its own div.